# Apache spark : JavaPairRDD Cogroup function gives wrappers$iterable, how to traverse it?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark 1.1.0. During the implementation I am invoking cogroup on `JavaPairRDD<String, SomeClassObjects>`.

The results returned by JavaPairRDD are in the form of `<String,  wrappers$iterable>`.

Does anyone have any idea, how to iterate  `wrappers$iterable` in Java? I have tried casting it to Iterable or JavaIterableWrapperSerializer,  but they both throw a ClassCastException.

Code is :

JavaPairRDD mtPairRDD has results of type `Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj>`

JavaPairRDD mcPairRDD has results of type `Tuple2<String,ClassMCObj>`

```
JavaPairRDD mCmTPairRDD = mcPairRDD.cogroup(mtPairRDD, 100);
List        lst         = mCmTPairRDD.collect()

        for(int i=0;i <= lst2.size(); i++) {
            Tuple2    obj1    = (Tuple2) lst2.get(i);
            String    mCompId = (String) obj1._1();

            Tuple2     obj2   = (Tuple2) obj1._2();
            ClassMCObj mcBean = (ClassMCObj) obj2._1(); //ClassCastException:due to wrappers$iterable               
            ClassMTObj mcT    = (ClassMTObj) obj2._2(); //ClassCastException:due to wrappers$iterable
        }
```

I have tried casting above as

```
Iterable mcBean = (Iterable) obj2._1()
```

or

```
JavaIterableWrapperSerializer mcBean = (JavaIterableWrapperSerializer) obj2._1();
```

but all the type cast options throws Exception.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Looks like something is missing here:  "The results returned by JavaPairRDD are in the form of ."  Try clicking the **edit** link under your post and putting that part inside back ticks.

Comment: @Paul : I have done the editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the raw types `JavaPairRDD` and `List`, the compiler can help you find the real problem. You were converting a object to a wrong type. Here is my fix to your codes:

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj>> mcPairRDD = null;
    JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, ClassMCObj>> mtPairRDD = null;

    JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj>>, Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMCObj>>>> mCmTPairRDD
            = mcPairRDD.cogroup(mtPairRDD, 100);
    List<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj>>, Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMCObj>>>>> lst = mCmTPairRDD.collect();
    for (Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj>>, Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMCObj>>>> kv : lst) {
        String key = kv._1();
        Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj>> v1 = kv._2()._1();
        Iterable<Tuple2<String, ClassMCObj>> v2 = kv._2()._2();
        for (Tuple2<String, ClassMTObj> kv1 : v1) {
            //...
        }
        for (Tuple2<String, ClassMCObj> kv2 : v2) {
            //...
        }
    }
```